# How can I tell google to index http instead of https version of my site?

Tags: tomcat, servlet-filters, google-search, google-crawlers, google-custom-search

My site requests an ssl client certificate when first establishing an https connection.

The browser's Javascript API offers no control over this, neither the backend's Servlet API: The only way to ask for the certificate again is to close all browser windows and start all over again*.

So I want my users to get to the site through any http page, see all links http, and when they log in they are redirected to the https version of the site.

Google indexes https as more authoritative than http, so they are keeping me from that.

I've been told to use canonical links when I am on http and regular when on https but that won't be easy, particularly with static content.

Is there any way I can change that without changing my whole codebase? Like a google search console option or something?

Or maybe some tomcat setting or valve / servlet filter that can keep the service from serving https content to google crawler?

**I've found a solution to this but it requires that I have control over DNS records so the server's hostname when requesting the client certificate can change on each login request (like f63a47c8.mydomain.com, a234e12b.mydomain.com, etc.) establishing a fresh SSL connection, and a very expensive CA signed "wildcard" server certificate that validates all those possible subdomains (very expensive compared to a certificate for a single host like www.mydomain.com).*

Comment: https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2014/08/https-as-ranking-signal.html

Comment: Not interested on my ranking at all. I need the best possible user experience, and right now the best I can do is users getting to the site through http, not https, then switch to https on login. This should ideally happen both from google search and google cse results but I'm happy if I can fix it just for CSE. Right now I am considering patching CSE results to replace https with http on result links. It's dirty and can break anytime but it will work. Any alternative ideas are welcomed :-)

Comment: Just to be clear: you have both HTTP and HTTPS sites, and you want Google to index the HTTP version but not the HTTPS version? Do you have different content on certain pages depending upon the URL scheme being used? Or do you want Google to only offer the HTTP version as the link target for your (Google) search result(s)?

Comment: It's the same content in both HTTP and HTTPS versions. I want google to only offer the HTTP version as the link target for google search results on my site. This is because when you land on HTTPS on my site an SSL client certificate is requested. This is part of the authentication scheme: users can log in to this site using their username and password or the credentials on their electronic ID card (Spanish eDNI) after using the certificate on this card to establish an SSL connection (HTTPS) to my site.

Comment: I want landings to be all HTTP and control the HTTP->HTTPS switch on my login page on certificate login request, otherwise the HTTPS connection will trigger the certificate request.

Comment: I know it is not a perfect solution, but after applets got obsolete, HTTPS client certificate is the only integrated solution that does not require the user to install an app for the specific purpose of certificate authentication. If at least there was a universal app for everybody's web certificate authentication needs I could require the users to install it, but that is not the case.

Comment: So, back to HTTPS client cert, I would need a wildcard server certificate and generating bogus subdomains all pointing to the authentication server to be able to disable client certificate request on the main domain (therefore being able to force a new SSL connection on each login, and being able to have https landing pages with no client certificate request). That kind of wildcard server certificate is expensive, and I have no control over DNS records, so I opted from HTTP->HTTPS switch control and no HTTPS landing pages.